Hubspot website uses several css files to generate the layout of the site. How do I "convert" my site; so that it looks the same?
I am currently in the process of migrating a Hubspot website to a different platform.  However, just about every single webpage has components that link to css files located on Hubspot's servers which I cannot access.  Hubspot has explained that the files are used to generate the layouts of the site, and I cannot download them.
I'm hoping someone here has experience removing all the Hubspot-specific components while maintaining all the content and themes of the website, or knows enough about what I'm talking about to provide some help.  Do I need to make new css layout files, or is there a more simple solution?
I am migrating the site to GoDaddy which uses Cpanel or Wordpress.  I've currently got everything on Cpanel and am updating all Hubspot specific links to the Cpanel links.
I am not a website developer but have just enough experience to be asked to do this.  Commenting out the lines pointing to Hubspot's servers makes the visual theme disappear which is not ideal.  I will happily share an example webpage if needed.
Thanks
